# Trying to plot a random series on a chart with matplotlib, but the chart will not display when the programe is ran.

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, charts

The following code will run with no errors, but the chart that I am trying to display will not pop up. I see the screen blink when I run the program like the chart is going to load but that is it, just a quick flash of the screen. Then my command line reads "press any key to continue" which is normal when my programs are finished running, but there is no chart???

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

seedval = 111111

np.random.seed(seedval)
s= pd.Series(np.random.randn(1096),index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01','2014-12-31'))

walk_ts = s.cumsum()

walk_ts.plot()
```

This is the output

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. It works for me.

Comment: It must be something on my computer as far as settings

Comment: @ZacAttack did you tried this line: `% matplotlib inline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you're doing this in a script, interactive python session or ipython. In the first case you need to call `plt.show()` at the end to show any figures. That's what you can do in a regular interactive python session as well. In ipython you're better off using `%matplotlib inline` to set everything up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line at the top of your code:

```
% matplotlib inline
```

Here is a good example using your data:

[image]